# How does one send a REST request to an annotated GRPC endpoint?

Tags: rest, grpc, http2

I am not receiving a valid response when `curl`ing the REST annotated endpoint from the GRPC protobuf

I'm currently running the [bookstore server](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/endpoints/bookstore-grpc-transcoding/bookstore_server.py) from [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/endpoints/bookstore-grpc-transcoding)

I've been able to hit the endpoint successfully via GRPC using the provided client.

```sh
$ python bookstore_client.py
ListShelves: shelves {
  id: 1
  theme: "Fiction"
}
shelves {
  id: 2
  theme: "Fantasy"
}
```

When I try to hit the corresponding REST endpoint, it gives me back a non-text (i.e. not JSON) response

```sh
$ curl --raw --http2 localhost:8000/v1/shelves 2>/dev/null | xxd
00000000: 0000 1804 0000 0000 0000 0400 4000 0000  ............@...
00000010: 0500 4000 0000 0600 0020 00fe 0300 0000  ..@...... ......
00000020: 0100 0004 0800 0000 0000 003f 0001 0000  ...........?....
00000030: 0806 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 00    ...............
```

I receive this response no matter what the uri is i.e. `/v1/foobar` gives the same result

Here are the relevant lines from the [protobuf](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/endpoints/bookstore-grpc-transcoding/bookstore.proto)

```proto
  rpc ListShelves(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (ListShelvesResponse) {
    // Define HTTP mapping.
    // Client example (Assuming your service is hosted at the given 'DOMAIN_NAME'):
    //   curl http://DOMAIN_NAME/v1/shelves
    option (google.api.http) = { get: "/v1/shelves" };
  }
```

I expected the same response that the python client gave me but I'm receiving a non-text response from the GRPC server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that example, port 8000 is the gRPC, not the REST endpoint.

To run the endpoint that follows the annotations you need to run the Extensible Service Proxy, from the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/transcoding):

*"Cloud Endpoints supports protocol transcoding so that clients can access your gRPC API by using HTTP/JSON. The Extensible Service Proxy (ESP) transcodes HTTP/JSON to gRPC."*

The REST endpoint will be served on a different port via ESP `--http_port` option.